# VotingClassifier in sklearn.ensemble ImportError

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, python-import, random-forest

I am trying to implement multiple learning classifiers in python. I have 5 random forest classifiers in the code but now I am not able to import the `VotingClassifier` function from `sklearn.ensemble`.

When I write this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
```

the error says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name VotingClassifier
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like it's only available under the dev version `0.17.0`, it's not in `0.16.1`

Answer (score 3):

I am the person who implemented the `VotingClassifier` in scikit-learn. Sorry for the confusion, I just stumbled upon the "examples" section in the scikit-learn 16.1 documentation. This is a little bit misleading, the `VotingClassifier` is already implemented but will be in the next version of scikit-learn 0.17.

If you want to use it "already" you have 2 options:

1) you could install the current scikit-learn dev version available via GitHub: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn (instructions are in the Readme)

2) alternatively, you could use it from `mlxtend` as `EnsembleClassifier` (http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/docs/classifier/scikit-learn_ensemble_classifier/) until the new scikit-version comes out. The `mlxtend` package is a little "playground" of mine where I upload some examples and functions that I find useful at times.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sebastian, I installed mlxtend but it looks like it is dependent on sklearn.pipeline._name_estimators, which is not in 16.1 as far as I can tell.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I think the documentation for this was accidentally "leaked" into the scikit-learn 16.1 version. However, scikit-learn 0.17 just came out last week or so, and I recommend trying it from there -- if there's no good reason not to use it (lots of fixes and improvements :))

Comment: I didn't realize sklearn had upgraded to 0.17!  I upgraded and its working perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: @SebastianRaschka: I am not able to import EnsembleClassifier using this following line of code : "from mlxtend.sklearn import  EnsembleClassifier". Error : "No module named sklearn" . Any suggestion to solve this problem? import mlxtend and import sklearn is both working.

Comment: @PappuJha Thx for letting me know. A while back, I changed it to `from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleClassifier` Which mlxtend version were you using? I am updating mlxtend sometime soon anyway and can fix this problem in one swoop then if it still exists.

Comment: @SebastianRaschka: Thanks for your reply. I figured out that it works well with from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleClassifier.

Comment: @PappuJha Thanks for letting me know; glad to hear that it works now!

Answer (score 0):

### Q: How can I fix this?

Your issue is clear & solve-able. The devil hides in the detail. **`VotingClassifier`** was announced in a scikit-learn changelog to be the add-on right for the still-wet-ink release of `0.17.0`.

If you are running `Anaconda / conda` package-manager for python, check:

**`$ conda search —all scikit-learn`** and

**`$ conda depends scikit-learn`** to verify any newly added dependencies

**`$ conda create -n (test-0-17-0-sklearn) scikit-learn`** for creating a new, separate, `conda`-named / -controlled environment for running python altogether with a sure sklearn ver. 0.17.0 for your further DEV/TEST

### A: In any case, wrap the import into a `try:` { ... } `except:` { ... }

```
try:
    from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
except:
    try:
        import sklearn
        print "WARNING: [VotingClassifier] not available\n",
              "WARNING: [import sklearn] reports version: ",
              sklearn.__version__, "\n"+60*"|"
    except:
        print "WARNING: impossible to [import sklearn] at all\n",
              60*"|"
```